# Dataframe Koalas to Delta Table: ERROR: An error occurred while calling o237.save

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, databricks

I read a couple of csv files using Pandas from my driver node, I converted the Pandas Dataframe to a Koalas Dataframe, and finally, I wanna insert the data from Koalas into a Delta table but I obtained an error:

```
import databricks.koalas as ks
import pandas as pd
import glob
all_files = glob.glob('/databricks/driver/myfolder/')
li = []
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=None, header=0)
    li.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(li, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
df = ks.from_pandas(frame)              
df.to_delta('dbfs:/FileStore/filesTest/%s' % tablename, mode='append')
```

> ERROR: An error occurred while calling o237.save. :
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find the REPL id in Spark
>   local properties. Spark-submit and R doesn't support transactional
>   writes from different clusters. If you are using R, please switch to
>   Scala or Python. If you are using spark-submit , please convert it to
>   Databricks JAR job. Or you can disable multi-cluster writes by setting
>   'spark.databricks.delta.multiClusterWrites.enabled' to 'false'. If
>   this is disabled, writes to a single table must originate from a
>   single cluster. Please check
>   https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-intro.html#frequently-asked-questions-faq
>   for more details.

[image]

Comment: I think is necessary to run the job as spark-python-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delta Lake supports transactional writes from multiple clusters in the same workspace in Databricks Runtime 4.2 and above. All writers must be running Databricks Runtime 4.2 or above.

**The following features are not supported when running in this mode:**

- SparkR
- spark-submit jobs
- Running a command using the REST API
- Client-side encryption
- Server-Side Encryption with Customer-Provided Encryption Keys
- S3 paths with credentials in a cluster that cannot access AWS Security Token Service

Make sure:

- If you are using R, please switch to Scala or Python.
- If you are using spark-submit , please convert it to Databricks JAR job.

**Reference:** "[Delta Lake - Introductory Notebooks](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/intro-notebooks.html#deltaquickstart-python)" and "[Delta - FAQs](https://docs.databricks.com/delta/delta-faq.html)".

Hope this helps.